# How to make send() function accept byte string as input which gets updated continuously?

Tags: python

```
l="7cer478jhbf4567"
s2.send()
print(s.recv(4095))
```

The `variable l` holds a hashed string which will be updated continuously.`S2.send()` accepts only byte string something like this `b"7cer478jhbf4567"`.How can I make `S2.send()` accept byte string which keeps changing continuously as input?

Comment: `send` takes a parameter. Your example doesn't have one. I already fixed the quotes, but I let you fix the rest.

Comment: what about `s2.send(l.encode())` ??

Comment: `bytes` are also immutable. Means that you have to call a method or use a global structure with the data which is updated by some other mean.

Comment: s2.send(l.encode()) worked fine